# How to use Power BI Sparkline like Excel

Tags: excel, powerbi, sparklines

Is it possible to create a sparkline in power bi desktop without using date. for example I have 3 columns which have their own values. I want to show these values in a column which is a sparkline exactly like spark line in excel. I need something like this in power bi:
[see this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5wgV.png)

How can I create it? What should be in x-axis and y-axis?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Power Bi doesn't work on pivoted (wide) tables like Excel does, but on stacked (long) tables instead. So you have to prepare your data accordingly. You can still show it in wide format afterwards using a Matrix visual. However, to add sparklines like in your example you would need a table that is just filtering by rows. Here you can add spaklines with `Value` on the *Y-axis* and `Column` on the *X-axis*. The aggregation doesn't matter for your sample data, so leave it to Sum.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Peter, but I don't want the sparkline to be drawn separately, actually I need the sparkline to be beside Value column in your example. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Use Excel. With Power BI you have to consider `filter context` - and that is obviously way beyond your skills.