# How to draw sparklines in a matrix in Power BI Desktop?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, sparklines

I am having a Measure table which is having a structure like this:[image: See this image]

What I want to do is to add sparkline chart beside column "c" in this Measure table. I am emphasizing on Measure table, because I know how to do that for regular table.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Power BI Sparkline like Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73352760/how-to-use-power-bi-sparkline-like-excel)

Comment: Using `measures` in the matrix visual makes no difference. The problem is that you cannot filter by column (a, b, c) w/o affecting the sparklines.

Comment: FYI, this is just a normal table. It is not a "measure" table.

Comment: Btw., you know it's a matrix visual, not a table, because of the perpendicular blue lines.